# Application is not centered on 4K monitor

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm having trouble running a simple application created in Delphi / Firemonkey, running on Windows with 4K monitor.

The application is not centered correctly on the screen, I am placing the `Position = ScreenCenter` property.

When the application is created in Delphi / VCL, I don't have this problem.

Could anyone help?

I'm using:

- Delphi 10.4.1 Professional
- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Monitor 4K Ultra HD 2160p (Philips Brilliance 288P)

Even forcing via code, it doesn't solve (FormShow):

```
Self.Top: = Trunc((Screen.Height - Self.Height) div 2); 
Self.Left: = Trunc((Screen.Width - Self.Width) div 2);
```

Comment: When you run the code and stop it in the debugger, what values do you see for `Screen.Width`, `Self.Width` and what is the actual width set for the form.

Comment: Make sure DPI Awareness is enabled in your project options. From what you have written so fat it seems that Application is not running with DPI Awareness enabled.

Comment: Hi,

It was set as default:
Project Options / Application / Manifest / DPI Awareness = "Per Monitor v2"

The options:
   DPI Awareness = "None",
   DPI Awareness = "Unaware"
   DPI Awareness = "GDI Scaling"
   The application was centralized, but the image of the running application was reduced in sharpness on the 4K monitor.
   The best option was "GDI Scaling", the sharpness just got a little better.


The other options available the image is 100% sharp, but unfortunately the application is not 100% centered on the monitor.
"System Aware",  "Per Monitor", "Per Monitor v2"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like FireMonkey has a bug that does not properly consider screen scaling for 4k monitors.  You will need to find the active scaling on your screen to fix this.  Try the following.  It works on Delphi 10.3.  I leave the Position property set to "Designed":

```
unit uForm1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    function Scale: Single;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure Center;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  FMX.Platform;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Center;
end;

procedure TForm1.Center;
begin
  Self.Left := Trunc((Screen.Width  - (Self.Width  * Scale)) / 2);
  Self.Top  := Trunc((Screen.Height - (Self.Height * Scale)) / 2);
end;

function TForm1.Scale: Single;
var
  ScrService: IFMXScreenService;
begin
  Result := 0.0;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService, ScrService) then
  begin
    Result := ScrService.GetScreenScale;
  end;
end;

end.

//FMX form
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form4'
  ClientHeight = 231
  ClientWidth = 327
  Position = Designed
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
end
```